# Share a folder with user 'Everyone' without asking to login?

Tags: shared-folders, xcopy

I shared a folder on a WinServer2012 with username 'Everyone' for read/write. From XP it doesn't ask for login, while from Win7 login box pops up.

How to accomplish to not being asked from Win7 too? I need it for upgrade xcopy purpose with .bat script at boot time. When asked I enter Everyone without a password and it lets me in. I need it to work automaticaly, without manualy entering username.

```
xcopy \\my_server\my_folder\my_file.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\My_Folder" /D /Q /Y
```

`my_folder` is shared with `Everyone`.

Comment: Try changing the NTFS permissions (On the security tab of the folder properties) to `Everyone` as well as the sharing permissions.

Comment: Thanks! Changed owner of a folder to 'Everyone' and gave full rights. Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows file sharing on Server 2012 takes NTFS permissions into consideration as well as the sharing permissions.

I wouldn’t advise to use `Everyone`, rather a local user account on the server or a domain account is preferable due to security reasons. However I understand in some circumstances it’s more convenient for a short period of time.

Try changing the NTFS permissions (On the security tab of the folder properties) to `Everyone` as well as the sharing permissions. This should solve the problem.